# If radio is checked show a div in asp.net mvc and jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make it so a certain div is hidden when a partialview loads and is displayed when a radio button is selected.  This is the jquery im using

```
<script>
$("input[name='JointOwner']").click(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "1") {
        $("#JointApplicantInfo").show();
    } else {
        $("#JointApplicantInfo").hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

When the form loads is showing the div and when i select the corresponding button that == 1 it hides the div and won't bring it back.

This is how my form looks

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.JointOwner, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.JointOwner, new { @class = "form-control", value="1"})&nbsp;Yes</label>
        <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.JointOwner, new { @class = "form-control", value = "0" })&nbsp;No</label>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.JointOwner)
    </div>
</div>

//Joint Applicant
<div id="JointApplicantInfo">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.JointFirstName, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-9">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.JointFirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.JointFirstName)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm not a JavaScript expert by any stretch, but my guess would be that `$(this).val() == "1"` is always evaluating to false so it's always falling into the branch that hides the div. You can test that pretty easy by adding a call to `alert()` to both branches and see which one executes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
$("#JointApplicantInfo").hide();

$("input[name='JointOwner']").change(function () {
    $("#JointApplicantInfo").toggle();
});
</script>
```

To hide the JointApplicantInfo div by default in the CSS...

```
#JointApplicantInfo {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I need the div to be hidden on load. This is causing my div to hide when i select the "1" value

Comment: I've updated my code if that's the case, you're better off hiding it in the CSS however.

Comment: Just set it to `display: none;` - have updated answer.